# Bruteforce all IP addresses on network with Hydra

Tags: brute-force, hydra

I have been tasked to pen test a computer on my network. I have done some social engineering to get the username and password of the device, and I know ssh is open on the computer. However, I do not know the device's ip address. Given a file of all the IP addresses on my network, how can I have Hydra attempt to log in to each device on the network with the given credentials? (I am not limited to hydra, any program that runs on macOS Catalina would work for me).

Comment: With a port scanner it is easy to sweep a network and determine which computers have SSH running. I am surprised you have not begun with this.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try listing the [options for Hydra](https://tools.kali.org/password-attacks/hydra) with `hydra -h` or [`man hydra`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/hydra.1.html)?

> `-M FILE` list of servers to be attacked in parallel, one entry per line

(No, you didn't.)